# Is there a way to get the middle of a way from Overpass API?

Tags: api, openstreetmap, sqldatareader, overpass-api

I´m trying to import several Ways and Nodes from the OSM. But i dont want to get the Ways as a way with different nodes, only the middle of the way.

In my case, all ways are an area (Parks, Parking etc.) and i only need one point - the middle of the area. I could calculate this after the request, but maybe theres a more elegant way?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the [`center`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Print_.28out.29) geometry output mode. See this [example](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4O4).

Comment: Please note that `center` will not be the centroid of your area and the center point doesn't necessarily have to be inside the area.If that's not a concern, you should be ok with `out center;`. See this example: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6Kb